# http caching - does changing the query string alter when to use cache response?

Tags: http, caching, okhttp

Lets assume my client is already set up for caching locally using okhttp. 
 so lets say in http that i have:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/search?var1=something&var2=somethingelse
```

and then i make that web call and it caches.

now if i make another call like this:

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/search?var1=different&var2=moredifferent
```

is this going to be cache call or is this considered a fresh request ? because im confused if caching also takes into account query parameters 
To me it should be a different call but im not sure if query parameters should be exactly the same for caching to be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different URIs, different cache entries. No problem.